# Coil whine-like noise on Ubuntu when moving mouse, more subtle on Windows, on a Dell Precision 7550

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hardware-failure, touchpad, noise

I am writing to find a solution to a very strange problem on my new laptop. On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, when I touch the touchpad (even not moving), my laptop emits a weird coil whine-like noise. To visualize what I am talking about here is a video of what I am doing:

[video link](https://streamable.com/ymd4zu)

The video shows how I touch the touchpad, and that a sound seems to be coming from the laptop speaker or from the back where the ventilators are. If I amplify/filter the sound to hear the phenomenon here is what we are talking about:

[sound link](https://sndup.net/4qf6/dell-precision-7550_trackpad-sound.mp3)

In this soundtrack one can hear alternatively the normal ventilator noise and a crackling sound. This crackling sound is the problem, and it's emitted when I touch the touchpad.

More than that, when I use the touchpad for some time, and I record a sound with the internal microphone in a quiet environment here is what I obtain:

[image: audacity recording]

The recording start with an exponential quickly decreasing to zero. It could look like a capacitor discharge. I don't know if it is normal or not, and if it is related to the above problem. But I think it was worth mentioning it, just in case that would be related.

---

The configuration is :

- [Dell Precision 7550](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/workstations-isv-certified/precision-7550-mobile-workstation/spd/precision-15-7550-laptop)
- [Intel Xeon W-10885M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201909/intel-xeon-w-10885m-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-30-ghz.html)
- [Nvidia Quadro RTX 5000](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/quadro-in-laptops/)
- 128GB ECC RAM
- 1TB SSD class 50
- Windows 10 x64 for workstation (pre-installed)
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (installed by myself)

The configuration is new/freshly installed.

---

Here is what I tested:

- In Ubuntu:

  - As soon as a finger touches the touchpad, the sound is emited
  - Cannot really tell if it is a coil whine sound or if it is coming from the internal speaker
  - Also happens when moving the mouse pointer around using an external mouse
  - Also happens when the sound is muted
  - Also happens when headphones are plugged
  - Happens regardless of whether the embedded or integrated graphics card is used
  - Happens regardless of whether the laptop screen is used or an external screen
  - Does **not** seem to happen when an external USB microphone is plugged ([Blue Yeti Pro](https://www.bluemic.com/fr-fr/products/yeti-pro/)) and is recording sound (the noise still happens when the microphone is just plugged and does not record sound)
  - Also happens when starting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from a live-usb key
- In Windows:

  - When before starting Windows the computer was turned off for some time (cold start):

    - Does not really seem to happen with one-finger gesture on the touchpad
    - Does not really seem to happen with external mouse
    - Very subtle noise, "sometimes", when using two-finger gestures to scroll down
  - When just before starting Windows, the computer was running Ubuntu:

    - Seem to happen with one-finger gestures on the touchpad (even though more subtle than when running Ubuntu)
    - Seem to happen with multi-finger gestures on the touchpad (even though more subtle than when running Ubuntu)
- In the BIOS:

  - No noise whatsoever is emitted, including when I move the mouse pointer around

---

At this point, I have literally no idea of what is going on, whether it is a software problem, a hardware problem (even though it does not seem to happen in the BIOS), or the interaction of both. I do not know if it is coming from a capacitor, the speaker, the CPU, the graphics card, the SSD... Any help to better characterize the problem (and hopefully fix it) would be very welcome.

---

**Questions:**

- **Any idea of other things to test to better characterize the problem?**
- **Any idea of where the problem can be coming from?**
- **Any idea of how to solve the problem?**

Note: since the computer is under warranty and everything I would like to avoid to open it.

Comment: Dell laptops especially the Precision 7550 series have coil whine issue.
I have bought this laptop Dec-2020 and it has coil whine issue. Check link "https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7550-electric-noise/m-p/7783545#M5215"

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

The issue is cause by excessive CPU-interrupts that are created when touching the touch-pad. The interrupts make the CPU got to max frequency on all cores.

The cpu load stresses the capacitors and this induces the 'coil-whine'.

Disabling Intel Speedshift in the BIOS-menu of the Precision 7550 (Under the power-management tab) + updating to Ubuntu 20.10 has resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I have a Latitude 5411 and disabling Speedshift was enough. So I can stay on 20.04. Thanks for the answer.

Pay attention that Speedshift and Speedstep are different things.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: The issue came back, and I cannot solve it with disabling the Speedshift only anymore. In fact I cannot solve the issue at all. I tested it with Ubuntu 20.04 Kubuntu 22.04 and Nixos 23.05 and 23.11.

If I make the CPU to be on a fixed clock, it kind of goes away, but makes the laptop unusable in real life scenarios.